# How to resolve https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository

Tags: kubernetes

I am working on helm 2 and trying to deploy Tiller as pod.

```
>helm init --service-account tiller
```

But i am getting below Error:
Error: error initializing: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml: dial tcp 172.217.2.240:443: connect: connection timed out

Has anyone faced this error and if yes , what is the recommended way to overcome this for helm2?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: yes, I am , I am using proxies also to reach outside

Comment: You probably hit this: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4326

Comment: which helm version you use? as per github - it should work fine starting from v2.11.0

Comment: For CI/CD client side `helm init --stable-repo-url=https://charts.helm.sh/stable --client-only`

Answer (score 70):

Helm versions prior to `2.17.0` have the deprecated https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml as the default stable repository, which no longer resolves. The new repo is https://charts.helm.sh/stable. You can choose to:

1. Use the  `--stable-repo-url` argument to specify the new repository:

   ```
   helm init --stable-repo-url https://charts.helm.sh/stable --service-account tiller
   ```
2. Use the  `--skip-refresh`  argument and replace the stable repo:

   ```
   helm init --client-only --skip-refresh
   helm repo rm stable
   helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
   ```
3. Upgrade helm to `2.17.0` or later.

Comment: I experienced the same issue with dtzar/helm-kubectl:2.16.1

Comment: Helm 2.17.0 also changed the default repo URL, so an alternate solution is to upgrade to Helm 2.17.0 (or 3).

Comment: I too faced the same problem while installing  chart which had a dependency and the repo was updated to dependencies:
  - name: mysql
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
    version: 1.4.0 ,   updated repository and it solved the  problem.

Answer (score 23):

```
helm init --client-only --skip-refresh
helm repo rm stable
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

Comment: Only code answer could be done more valuable if explanation/details are added.

Comment: For first line I get ```Error: unknown command "init" for "helm"```.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66881098/75799

Answer (score 3):

update the urls like below solved my issue

Name :   stable
Old Location:https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
New Location:https://charts.helm.sh/stable

Name :   incubator
Old Location:https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com
New Location:https://charts.helm.sh/incubator

Reference:https://helm.sh/blog/new-location-stable-incubator-charts/

Answer (score 2):

repo is not avail. use below repo.

```
k8scka@master:~$ helm3 repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
"stable" has been added to your repositories
k8scka@master:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when targeting a `helm_release` resource in Terraform that was using the helm2 provider. We tracked it down to the root cause being a missing `~/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml` file that helm2 uses, which must be also used by the Terraform provider.

The file can be recreated with a helm v2 client with

```
helm2 init --stable-repo-url https://charts.helm.sh/stable --client-only
```

There is no need to keep the helm v2 client afterwards if you only want to use Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

Just for history and maybe anyone else will face also. Community answer.

Errors like `"Error: error initializing: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml: dial tcp 172.217.2.240:443: connect: connection timed out"` are typically due to problems with Proxy and non-direct connection.

This was discussed in related github issue [Cannot perform helm init behind proxy](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4326), lots have same problems. As per topic - users can have such problems with some of helm versions. Its recommended to use it  starting from [v2.11.0](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.11.0)