# helm init failed is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch 403 Forbidden

Tags: kubernetes-helm

is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml : 403 Forbidden

helm init start failing today, we are using helm version `HELM_VERSION: v2.13.0` in our CI/CD.

```
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Error: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" 
is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: 
Failed to fetch https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml : 403 Forbidden
```

While it was working fine a day ago. Here are the logs that I received while running `init` command.

```
$ helm init --client-only
Creating /root/.helm 
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Error: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml : 403 Forbidden
```

There are similar questions [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63947773/kubernetes-helm-not-a-valid-chart-repository) but that seems different and also I am not behind a proxy like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62088486/3288890).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Since November 13, 2020, the new location for the `stable` repository is https://charts.helm.sh/stable and the new location for the `incubator` repository is https://charts.helm.sh/incubator.

Try:

```
helm init --stable-repo-url=https://charts.helm.sh/stable --client-only
```

or

```
$ helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
$ helm repo update
```

| Name | Old Location | New Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stable | https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com | https://charts.helm.sh/stable |
| incubator | https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com | https://charts.helm.sh/incubator |

- [Ref](https://helm.sh/blog/new-location-stable-incubator-charts/)

Comment: thanks, let me update your answer. I have to specify stable repo in init command `init --stable-repo-url=https://charts.helm.sh/stable`.

Comment: however, the helm installer still comes with the old repo urls

Answer (score 7):

This fixed it for me:

```
helm repo add "stable" "https://charts.helm.sh/stable" --force-update
```