# Gitlab-CI failure Error: error initializing: Looks like link is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached:

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running auto deploy to GCP through Gitlab, I'm using this auto-deploy script https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml as my guide. Now there's this template that's being used for the deploy and it's failing at the job `auto-deploy download_chart` and it throws this error(this error is very recent, started about a week ago):

```
$ auto-deploy download_chart
 Creating /root/.helm 
 Creating /root/.helm/repository 
 Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
 Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
 Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
 Creating /root/.helm/starters 
 Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
 Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
 Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
 Error: error initializing: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml : 403 Forbidden
```

This is the script it runs, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml and fails at the `auto-deploy download-chart`. I think the reason is changing location of charts because of this blog https://helm.sh/blog/new-location-stable-incubator-charts/ but I'm not sure.

I have seen duplicates of this question but it's different as I am using a CI that has the job for deploying, just wondering if there's a way I can change the ci or there's a new template that uses the current stable helm url.

How can I fix this error? Anyone with any understanding will be of great help! Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [helm init failed is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Failed to fetch 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65407317/helm-init-failed-is-not-a-valid-chart-repository-or-cannot-be-reached-failed-to)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading the Gitlab instance from `13.2` to `13.6`.